# Simplify and FullSimplify do not simplify a simple term

Tags: mathematica

Why don't `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` work on:  $\frac{\sqrt{a + \cos \theta}}{\sqrt{\frac{a + \cos \theta}{1 + a}}}$?

```
FullSimplify[ Sqrt[a + Cos[\[Theta]]] /Sqrt[(a + Cos[\[Theta]])/(
 1 + a)]]
```

Even if $\cos \theta \leq 0$ the term should simplify.... no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give assumptions, try this:

```
    FullSimplify[ Sqrt[a + Cos[\[Theta]]] /Sqrt[(a + Cos[\[Theta]])/(
 1 + a)], Assumptions->a>1]
```

or try this:

```
    Simplify[ Sqrt[a + Cos[\[Theta]]] /Sqrt[(a + Cos[\[Theta]])/(
 1 + a)], Assumptions->a>1]
```